# util.Properties bug corrupting .properties file on win10

Tags: java

This bug is happening only in win10. Currently in win7 it does not happen.

Essentially I write some text that the user has inputted in various fields.

I use this to save all the info the user wrote, so when the application is relaunched the info is already there.

Also, I call this class every time the user clicks a button.

With normal behavior, the application runs fine on win7, and it saves everything properly. With win10 though, saving effectively "corrupts" the file, or at least, it makes it empty.

```
package whatever;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class SaveFile {

    public static void mainSave(String[] args) {

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        OutputStream output = null;

        try {

            String instaPathCombined = "config.properties";
            output = new FileOutputStream(instaPathCombined);


            // set the properties value, the get methods all retrieve a string.
            prop.setProperty("a", UI.geta());
            prop.setProperty("b", UI.getb());
            prop.setProperty("c", UI.getc());
            prop.setProperty("d", UI.getd());
            prop.setProperty("e", UI.gete());
            prop.setProperty("f", UI.getf());
            prop.setProperty("g", UI.getg());
            prop.setProperty("h", UI.geth());
            prop.setProperty("i", UI.geti());
            prop.setProperty("j", UI.getj());
            prop.setProperty("k", UI.getk());
            prop.setProperty("l", UI.getl());
            prop.setProperty("m", UI.getm());
            prop.setProperty("n", UI.getn());
            prop.setProperty("o", UI.geto());
            prop.setProperty("p", UI.getp());
            prop.setProperty("q", UI.getq());
            prop.setProperty("r", UI.getr());
            prop.setProperty("s", UI.gets());
            prop.setProperty("t", UI.gett());
            prop.setProperty("u", UI.getu());
            prop.setProperty("v", UI.getv());

            // save properties to project root folder   
            prop.store(output, null);

        } catch (IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (output != null) {
                try {
                    output.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }



}
```

I have no idea on why it does this.

Also, this is literally a win10 issue, no other factors matter here, as I tried it on a VM with a fresh win10 installation and it happened.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://i.imgur.com/qKt3BdI.png)

Comment: This is very odd, I'll release the full code, maybe it has something to do with it. @Mango

Comment: Can you provide an example of the contents of a “corrupted” file?

Comment: @VGR There aren't any. The file becomes empty.